# Finding the inverse of $y=\mu-\sigma\log\left[\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\right]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> What is the inverse of this function?
> $$y=\mu-\sigma\log\left[\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\right]$$

I've only calculated up to here:

$$\log\left[\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\right]=(\mu-y)/\sigma$$

and I guess that $\log[e^{-x}]=-x$ but can't find something for $\log(1+e^{-x})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log\left[\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\right]=\log\left[\frac1{e^x-1}\right]=-\log[e^x-1]=(\mu-y)/\sigma$$which gives$$x=\ln[1+e^{(y-\mu)/\sigma}]$$